# How to update the database, when changing a select option - PHP, AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, select

I have a table that i made in php, now i want to let the user to change the access level of each user, using a dropdown menu (select/option). For example:

[image]

Once the user presses general it sends the request to ajax, changing/updating the database instantly.

**admin.php**

```
    <?php
//database connection
include("db_conn.php");
include("session.php");

session_start();

$username = $_SESSION['logged_in']; //set the current user
$query = "SELECT `ID`, `Username`,`Name`, `DOB`, `Email`, `Access` FROM `users`";

$result =   $mysqli->query($query);
$row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);


    function show_table($myData)
    {
        echo "<table border=1 id='staff_table'>
        <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>DOB</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Access</th>
        </tr>";
        while ($row = $myData->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        {   
            $access= $row['Access'];
            $access2;


              $access_data = 1; //admin = level 1
              $access_data2 = 2; //general = 2
            if($access == 1)
            {
                $access = "Admin";
                $access2 = "General";

                $access_data = 1; //change when the page loads (depending what access level they are)
                $access_data2 = 2; //change when the page loads
            }
            else
            {

                $access = "General";
                $access2 = "Admin";

                $access_data = 2; //the reason i have these values is they 
                $access_data2 = 1; //change depending on what the user's access level is once the page loads
            }

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Username'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['DOB'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Email'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td id='" . $row['ID'] .  "'>";
            echo "<select name='admin_menu' class='admin_menu'>"; 
            echo '<option class="admin_option" value="' . $access_data2. '">' . $access . '</option>';
            echo '<option class="admin_option" value="' . $access_data. '">' . $access2 . '</option>';
            echo "</select>";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Admin Table</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.admin_menu').change(function() {
                    id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
                    level = $('.admin_menu  option:selected').val();
                    var request = $.ajax({
                      url: "changeLevel.php",
                      method: "POST",
                      data: { id : id, level: level },
                      dataType: "html"
                      });

                    request.done(function() {
                       //location.reload(); //reload page (if it actually updates)
                    });

                    });
                });
        </script>   
    </head>


    <body>
        <h1>Admin Table</h1>
        <?php show_table($result); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**changeLevel.php**

```
<?php
include("db_conn.php");

$id = $_POST['id'];
$level = $_POST['level'];

    $queryUpdate="UPDATE users SET Access='$level' WHERE ID='$id'";
    $update = $mysqli->query($queryUpdate);
?>
```

The user table is not updating, is there any other solution to this? Or can anyone see the problem? Thanks in advance, I'm pretty new to AJAX so all help is appreciated :)

Comment: @daremachine it's not updating lol :(

Comment: and ajax is successful? and what you see at server-side like var_dump($_POST); die;

Comment: do you have to use ajax ?

Comment: @IvanBarayev Nah, i dont

Comment: you need to check for errors. If your ajax was sent with status 200, then you need check php side, like $mysqli is ok, $id, $level are ok. I recommend to you wrap your query to try catch block and handle the exception, problem might be at database

Comment: try change level = $('.admin_menu  option:selected').val(); to level = $(this).val();, because you listen changes on the select and he had a selected value

Answer (score 3):

you could trigger the form post when there is a change on the field using

> onchange='this.form.submit()'

so your select box may look something like this

> ```
>   <form action='' method='post'>
>       <select name="dropdown" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
>           <option name="option1" value="option1">This is Option 1</option>            
>           <option name="option2" value="option2">This is Option 2</option>            
>       </select>
>   </form>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

first change this lines

```
echo "<select name='admin_menu' class='admin_menu'>"; 
echo '<option class="admin_option" value="' . $access_data2. '">' . $access . '</option>';
echo '<option class="admin_option" value="' . $access_data. '">' . $access2 . '</option>';
echo "</select>";
```

to

```
echo "<select name='admin_menu' class='admin_menu' id='Selectid' onchange='postlist();'>"; 
echo '<option class="admin_option" value="'.$access_data2.'-'.$access.'">'.$access.'</option>';
echo '<option class="admin_option" value="'.$access_data.'-'.access2 .'">'.$access2.'</option>';
echo "</select>";
```

In changed lines I add `onchange=""` function and `id=""` to `"select"` tag, after I change the `<option value="">`; 
`"$access_data"` and `"$access"` added together with "-" for exploding the value.

JavaScript

```
<script>
    function postlist() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', 
        url: 'changeLevel.php', // here posting value to your php file
        data: $('#Selectid').val(), // here get the option value from select
        success: function (answer) {
            $("#ReportResult").html(answer) // here you can define an alert function for after success or you can use it with an id for showing the response
        }
    })
}
</script>
```

in changeLevel.php

```
<?php
include("db_conn.php");

$id = $_POST['id']; //here we get value like (13-Admin);
$ids = explode("-", $id); //and here we explode the $id value (explode mean split the value with "-" or you can define "space",",","." or another sign)

    $queryUpdate="UPDATE users SET Access='$ids[1]' WHERE ID='$ids[0]'";
    $update = $mysqli->query($queryUpdate);
?>
```

> PS = $ids[0] eq to id and $ids[1] eq to Level
>
> you can change this order easily

Comment: why this approach is better then original and why you avoid jQuery listeners if jquery is used?

Comment: My answer is a suggestion She not have to apply it, but accept it this is another way !

Comment: "Do this" type answers are generally not very useful. Explain what is different and why it should be done this way. What problems are you fixing and how did you achieve it?